# Blender 2.8 goes off when I click on material buttons

Tags: materials

I’m a new user of blender. I downloaded and started using Blender 2.80-windows 64, 4 days ago. I’ve been using some YouTube videos to learn.
My problem:
In the shading workspace, whenever I click on “browse material to be linked button” and select a material to apply, Blender goes off and I have to restart the app. This started happening after I had named a second material and wanted to apply it. There’s a material button at the bottom right side of the UI which also causes the app to go off whenever I click on it. 
I’ve no idea what to do. Has anyone been faced this challenge and how was it overcome?
My system: HP Elitebook 8560w running Windows 10 with 12 GB RAM and 2 GB GPU

Comment: If blender crashes consistently whenever you perform this operation then please report a bug. To report a proper bug that helps developers I suggest you watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTD0OJq_rF4

Answer (score 0):

Same thing Happened to me to, I found switching to Cycles Render is a bit more stable on Intel Hardware drivers and deselecting add-on`s that are not being used.

Comment: You’re suggestion worked! I’m very grateful. Thank you Gnus!